# UIActivityViewController: Video Share to Youtube

Tags: ios, youtube, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, custom-activity

Is there any way to share a video to **YouTube** site without using *custom* **UIActivity**? YouTube is not listed in **UIActicvityViewController** though YouTube app is installed on the device. Its not the case with **Vine, Vimeo** and other apps.Apps are listed if they are installed on the device. Please clarify me about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youtube app does not include a share extension and Youtube has never been a system provided activity item.  The built-in photos app probably has created its own UIActivity item for Youtube.